# zsh: echo F# -- no match found

Tags: bash, zsh

Let's try the command in `zsh` with the default setting:

```
echo F#
```

which will cause the following error message:

```
zsh: no match found: F#
```

My stackoverflow search indicates that it can be turned off by setting `setopt nonomatch`, then `zsh` behaves more like `bash`: glob the pattern, and pass it to the program if no match is found. It works like a charm.

My curiosity does not stop here. I still have one question: what the `#` is trying to match in the above statement? I searched the bash and zsh document yet didn't get a clear answer. Hope someone can clear my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to the have the `EXTENDED_GLOB` option set. In that case, `F#` is treated as a pattern that matches zero or more occurrences of the letter `F` (cf. the regular expression `F*`).

When you run `echo F#`, the shell tries to expand `F#` to any files whose names are the empty string, `F`, `FF`. If there are none, the match fails, and with the `NOMATCH` option set (as it is by default), the failure produces the observed error.